# Xamarin.iOS: NSTemporaryDirectory()

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Is [`NSTemporaryDirectory()`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/1409211-nstemporarydirectory) available for Xamarin.iOS? I can't find something in the [Xamarin API](https://developer.xamarin.com/search?q=NSTemporaryDirectory). How is it related to [described directories here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_the_file_system/#Application_Directories)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the normal `GetTempPath` method to obtain the file path:

```
var temp = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath();
Console.WriteLine(temp);
```

Or if you need a `NSUrl`:

```
var nsURL = NSFileManager.DefaultManager.GetTemporaryDirectory();
Console.WriteLine(nsURL.AbsoluteUrl);
```

The `NSUrl` absolute url is the same path, just prefixed with `file://`

Comment: *Error CS1061 'NSFileManager' does not contain a definition for 'GetTemporaryDirectory' and no extension method 'GetTemporaryDirectory' accepting a first argument of type 'NSFileManager' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

Comment: @testing What version of `Xamarin.iOS` are you using?

Comment: 9.8.2.22 (VS2015)

Comment: Old version, just use `System.IO.Path.GetTempPath` then and convert to a NSUrl if needed, i.e. `new NSUrl(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath())`

Comment: OK, since iOS 10 available.

Comment: @testing There was also 9.9.x releases before 10 came out... you can look at the github repo and to see when it was added to `Foundation`... I'm really surprised your version does not have it...